# How to pass a structure array element as argument to function?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct Ques
{
  int a;
}Q[5];
void sort(int a[])
{
 printf("any sort technique...");
}
void main() 
{
 sort(Q.a);
}
```

So this is the sample code.
I Want to access the whole struct element as array.

Comment: If you have an array of structures you cannot automatically convert this to an array of `int` or an array of any of the structure fields. Why do you need a structure if it contains only one field? It appears that you want to sort the `int a` fields in the structure array. Do you mean to sort the whole structure array based on the values of the `int a` fields?

Comment: @Bodo yeah that is i want!!

Comment: @MohammedArif Please [edit] your question and explain what you want. From your comment it is not even clear what "that is i want" refers to.

Comment: @Bodo As u said that  " Do you mean to sort the whole structure array based on the values of the int a fields? "  that is what i required!!!


And for that previous comment i was telling "yeah that is what i want"...sorry for the mistake!

Comment: **[edit] your question and add all explanation there**. If you want to sort the structures, why do you think that you have to pass an `int a[]` instead of a `struct Ques q[]`. Apparently your real question might be something like "How to sort an array of structures based on a the value of structure field `int a`?" Then you should write this in your question.

Comment: @Bodo see if my structure contains two elements example int a and int b. I want to sort the structure based on 'a' for the first time and sort based on 'b' for the second time. How can i do that?

Comment: Don't ask your questions in comments. Don't write requested clarification in comments. **Please [edit] the question** and add all relevant information there.

Comment: Comments are not part of the question and might be deleted any time. If an information is relevant, it must go into the body of your question. Not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Ques
{
  int a;
} Q[5];

void sort(struct Ques array[], int size)
{
   printf("any sort technique...");

   // just some demo
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     printf("array[%d].a = %d\n", i, array[i].a);
}

int main() 
{
 // put some data into Q
 sort(Q, 5);
}
```

`sort` needs two parameters:

- the pointer to the array to sort
- the size of the array (unless you only ever want to sort array of some fixed size

Comment: @Bodo You're right. edited. I wanted to do `sort(Q, sizeof(Q) / sizeof(Q[0]))`, but this might be out of scope for the OP for the moment.